# how to check if the image is deformed or not

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, android

I am using OpenCV4Android version 2.4.11. I am trying to change the prespective of any rectangular shape detected in the frame retrieved from the camera. Sometimes, when i change the prespective of the detected rectangular object i get a deformed/incomplete image as the one shown below.

the code posted below is to show how i change the prespective of a setected object.

is there any way using opeCV to check if the image is deformed/incomplete? because if the image is deformed/incomplete i would not display it.

please let me know how to do so.

**code**:

```
 MatOfPoint2f src2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
 MatOfPoint2f dst2f = new MatOfPoint2f();

                    src2f.fromArray(new Point(pointsBoundingRect.x, pointsBoundingRect.y), new Point(pointsBoundingRect.x, pointsBoundingRect.y + pointsBoundingRect.height),
                            new Point(pointsBoundingRect.x + pointsBoundingRect.width, pointsBoundingRect.y + pointsBoundingRect.height), new Point(pointsBoundingRect.x + pointsBoundingRect.width, pointsBoundingRect.y));
                    dst2f.fromArray(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0 + mMatInputFrame.height()),
                            new Point(0 + mMatInputFrame.width(), 0 + mMatInputFrame.height()), new Point(0 + mMatInputFrame.width(), 0));

                    Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(src2f, dst2f);
                    Mat rotated = new Mat();
                    Imgproc.warpPerspective(mMatInputFrame, rotated, transmtx, mMatInputFrame.size(), Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR, Imgproc.BORDER_REFLECT, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

                    if (rotated.width() > rotated.height()) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated.cols(), rotated.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(rotated, bitmap);
                        final Bitmap finalBitmap = bitmap;
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mIVCapture.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

**image**:

[image]

**update**

after setting a bigger destination size and after setting the borders type to BORDER_CONSTANT i gor the following results. please realize the while horizontal strip in the image

[image]

Comment: Unclear. If you change the perspective (using `cv::warp()` ?), then it is perfectly normal that the image is getting transformed... Please clarify you question, with some snippet of code showing what you are doing.

Comment: @kebs i updated my question ..please have a look

Comment: Set a bigger destination size in `warpPerspective`, with `BORDER_CONSTANT`. You can then easily crop to remove the extra border.

Comment: @Miki please see the update section

Comment: The white line is probably due some error while converting to Bitmap. ARGB_8888 probably need a CV_8UC4. What type is your `rotated` mat?

Comment: @Miki actually i do not know..but i tried the following method as follows: Log.d(TAG, "rotated.type(): " + rotated.type()); and it returned 0

Comment: That's `CV_8UC1`. Are you checking the type _after_ the call to `warpPerspective`?

Comment: @Miki after WarpPerspective it is 24

Comment: It's a CV_8UC3 and it's correct... I can't tell why you're getting that wierd white line, but I don't think is related to the warping itself.

Comment: @Miki ok. but can u please tell me whther there is any way to crop the resultant image? i mean the image after correcting the perspective "the one is deformed with while horizontal trip on the middle"..i want to have only the image of the card itself no surrounding background. how can i do that please

Comment: You know the color of the border (you can set it along with BORDER_CONSTANT). Use `inRange` to segment the color, and keep the connected component that touches the border. Take the boundingRect of the inverse of its mask. Or you can apply the same warping to a white mask the same size as your image. You can then simply take the bounding rect of the warped mask.

Comment: @Miki but the background color is changing..i mean i would not place the card on the same background each time..the background might change

Comment: I was talking about the border color of the warped image, not the background of your image

Comment: @Miki actually, in warpPerspective method i set the color to Scalar(255, 255, 255) but actually there are no while colors at all surrounds the borders of the resultant image posted above

Comment: Set the color to `Scalar(0,255,0)` and see if the white line becomes green

Comment: @Miki i changed it to green and black but unfortunately nothing appears surrounding the borders